# IP Canonicalization , Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess

I checked my site with online SEO checker and it suggested that I have to fix this error:

```
Your site's IP xxx.xxx.xx.xxx does not redirect to your site's domain name.
```

So as suggested I added some code to my htacces file located in public directory. Of course replacing x's with IP adress.

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But then after app restart I checked again with SEO checker and again it shows the same error.
Here is my full htacces file:

```
PassengerAppRoot /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/darbs/

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
RailsEnv development
RackBaseURI /
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home3/ecotec11/ruby/gems/gems
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.darbs.ecotechno.lv$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.darbs.ecotechno.lv/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^173\254\28\107
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.darbs.ecotechno.lv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When you type in the browser's address window XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, does it change to www.yourdomain.com as a result of redirect?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh No, it just shows my hosting company's logo and message:There is no website configured at this address.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh I added full htaccess code.

Comment: `173\254\28\107` or `173\.254\.28\.107`?

Comment: Are you on a hosting server? Unless you have a dedicated IP, I think you cannot have its IP point to you and not anybody else.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.. Thanks

Comment: You probably can buy a dedicated IP from the hosting service. Then your `.hpaccess` may work (depending on their policies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Your actual IP 173.254.28.107 points to a hosting service. The hosting service cannot point to your site because it probably hosts thousands of other sites.

A solution might be to buy a dedicated IP from that hosting service. Depending on their policies, you might (or might not) have access to your own document root, or your public html directory might be your document root.

(2) If this were a dedicated server or at least dedicated IP, then the answer would be that you edited `.htaccess` located in a wrong place.

Place an `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

in the **default** document root, the one where the `index.html` that says "There is no website configured at this address" is located. You can either look for a file named `index.html` or see what is the default document root in the Apache config file.